# Operator '*' is ambiguous (C++)

Tags: c++, sfml

Recently I have been making a test "game" in C++ (to get used with SFML). I have made a Super Mario sprite as shown below

```
sf::Texture SuperMarioAnim;
if (!SuperMarioAnim.loadFromFile("img/image.png"))
{
    std::wcout << L"Συγγνώμη, η εικόνα SuperMarioAnim δεν υπάρχει ή διαγράφηκε";
}

sf::Sprite SuperMario;
SuperMario.setTexture(SuperMarioAnim);
SuperMario.setPosition(200, 2900);
```

I also made a player_speed integer, with the value of the speed of the player, obviously, and I also created a time object equal to the value we get from `clock.getElapsedTime()`:

```
int player_spd = 30;

while (window.isOpen())
{
    //...
    sf::Time time;
    time = clock.getElapsedTime();
    //...
}
```

However, when I tell the sprite to move in the X axis with this:

```
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
    SuperMario.move(sf::Vector2f((player_spd * time), 0));
```

I get this error: `1>c:\[directory]\visual studio 2017\projects\test_game\test_game\test_game.cpp(180): error C2593: 'operator *' is ambiguous` (line 180 is the SuperMario.move command right above)

Could someone specify what I did wrong? I am using Visual Studio 2017 and SFML 2.4

Comment: they are not of types that can be `*` together. You can't do `std::string` * `int` -> same thing here.You can make a function that handles these 2 argument types to do the `*`

Comment: @PYA But doesn't `clock.getElapsedTime()` return numeric values? Because `player_spd` is surely a numeric value (so we don't need to worry about this variable)

Comment: You should be able to multiply sf::Time and int's, if the operator* is overloaded. It looks like it is: https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Time.php
Try to cast the player_spd into float like this: sf::Vector2f(((float)player_spd * time), 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'clock.getElapsedTime()' returns a 'Time' object.  You have the option of returning a float from a 'Time' object as 'asSeconds()', 'asMilliseconds()', or 'asMicroseconds()'.  I believe this will solve your error, but am unable to test on my end.  I would also recommend changing 'player_spd' to a float.

```
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
    SuperMario.move(player_spd * time.asSeconds()), 0));
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

`sf::Time` defines these overloads of `operator*`<sup>[1](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Time.php)</sup>:

```
Time    operator* (Time left, float right)
    //Overload of binary * operator to scale a time value. 

Time    operator* (Time left, Int64 right)
    //Overload of binary * operator to scale a time value. 

Time    operator* (float left, Time right)
    //Overload of binary * operator to scale a time value. 

Time    operator* (Int64 left, Time right)
    //Overload of binary * operator to scale a time value.
```

The error indicates that overload resolution failed because it can't choose among them. `player_spd` is an `int`. And calling `operator*` will require converting it to either `float` or `Int64`. Neither is better than the other (according to the error message). So it's ambiguous.

You can cast, or just define `player_spd` as one of the types that `sf::Time` can be multiplied by.

Comment: So I need to make it a float, this is what you are implying, don't you?

Comment: @ToadTheMushroomCoder - Or `Int64`. It's rather odd actually. I would expect `Int64` to be an integer type larger than an `int`. So that would be a promotion, and would in fact rank better than a conversion to `float`. But seems to not be the case.

Comment: just cast it: ((float)player_spd). or (Int64)player_spd

Comment: @ToadTheMushroomCoder -- Or just use the correct type from the start, an `Int64` and not `int`.

Comment: @StoryTeller I changed player_spd to a float, and while it fixed the operand error, Vector2f does not like it and it gives an error `error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'sf::Vector2f'` I also tried casting but still same error

Comment: @ToadTheMushroomCoder do not multiply by Time, multiply by seconds for example: `float t = time.asSeconds();`

Comment: While this might be a possible solution in general, it won't help in this situation. If you multiply a `sf::Time` you'll get back a new `sf::Time` representing the new timespan (shorter or longer). This won't help, when you actually want to scale a number based on the time passed.